# Delphi XE2 - How to open only .mp3 files with a Multiselect and Unfiltered Opendialog

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

How to load to listview only .mp3 files using a unfiltered and multiselect opendialog? I'm using this method:

```
procedure TForm1.PlayClick(Sender: TObject);
  var i:integer;
  begin
  if opendialog1.execute  then
  begin
  if ExtractFileExt(opendialog1.FileName[i]) ='.mp3' then
  begin
  for I := 0 to opendialog1.files.Count - 1 do
  begin
  listview1.Items.Add.Caption:=extractfilename(opendialog1.Files[i]);
  end;
  end;
  end else
  begin
showmessage(opendialog1.Files[i]);
  end;
  end;
```

But i need a procedure that works like this:

If user open a folder with various type of extensions, the opendialog only add to the ListView files with .mp3 extension. I need a procedure that do not use a filter. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You had several issues in your code. the `i` variable is not initialized, you must check for the extension inside of the for loop, Also you are checking the extension of the file using the `FileName[i]` property which get the current selected file (only valid in not multi-select mode), so you are comparing a element (char) of this property against the `.mp3` instead you must use the  `Files` property.

Try this

```
var
  i:integer;
  LItem : TListItem;
begin
  if opendialog1.execute  then
    for i := 0 to OpenDialog1.Files.Count - 1 do
     if SameText(ExtractFileExt(opendialog1.Files[i]), '.mp3') then
     begin
       LItem:=listview1.Items.Add;
       LItem.Caption:=ExtractFileName(OpenDialog1.Files[i]);
     end;
end;
```

Comment: Why not just setting the `Filter` property?